# Question regarding the frequency approximation of a pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator, dimensional-analysis

I have a problem with the formula for the frequency of a pendulum oscillation for small angles.

If I use torque and angular momentum, approximating $\sin\theta$ to $\theta$ with a 2nd order Taylor polynomial, I get the standard formula of $$\omega = \sqrt {\frac g L}.$$

However, if I use the potential energy, I seem to get a nonsensical answer. Setting the $0$ potential at the ceiling, the $y$ coordinate of the mass $m$ as a function of $\theta$ is: $$h=-L\cos\theta,$$ therefore the gravitational potential energy is $$U(\theta)=-mgL\cos\theta.$$ Using a 2nd order Taylor polynomial this time, I get: $$U(\theta) \approx -mgL(1-\frac {\theta^2} 2)=-mgL+\frac 1 2mgL\theta^2=C+\frac 1 2k_{eff}\theta^2.$$ By this, the frequency of the pendulum for small angles should actually be $$\omega = \sqrt {\frac {k_{eff}} m}=\sqrt {gL},$$ which doesn't even make sense in terms of the dimensions. So what did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule (a baby version of Lagrangian mechanics) is that if you're working in terms of a variable $q$, and the kinetic and potential energy have the form 
$$K = \frac12 m_{\text{eff}} \left( \frac{dq}{dt} \right)^2, \quad V = \frac12 k_{\text{eff}} q^2$$
then the frequency of oscillations is 
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k_{\text{eff}}}{m_{\text{eff}}}}.$$
The issue with your derivation is that you haven't used the right $m_{\text{eff}}$. You're working in terms of the variable $q = \theta$. The kinetic energy is 
$$K = \frac12 m v^2 = \frac12 m L^2 \left( \frac{d\theta}{dt} \right)^2$$
which means $m_{\text{eff}} = m L^2$. Plugging this in gives the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

Total system energy is potential + kinetics:
$E = (1/2)mv^2 - mgL + (1/2)mgL \theta^2 $

As it doesn't change with time:
$\frac{dE}{dt} = mv(\frac{dv}{dt}) + mgL \theta (\frac{d \theta} {dt}) = 0$

$m \omega L (\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2})L + mgL\theta \omega = 0$

$(\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}) = -\frac{g}{L} \theta$

So, $\omega^2 = \frac{g}{L}$